# How do I save dynamically generated API content from a view to a SQLite3 database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where the user can search for albums by artist. My search makes an API call to iTunes and I display the top 25 results as a simple table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Album</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @search_results.each do |album| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= album['artistName'] %></td>
        <td><%= album['collectionName'] %></td>
        <td><%= album['primaryGenreName'] %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Add to Library", albums_url, method: 'post' %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the last column I want to have a button that the user could click which would save that row (a specific album) to the database. I would only be saving the three columns listed to the database.

I'm having a little trouble figuring out the logic behind scraping my own page and saving those objects, and how that would work in my controller. For reference I have a simple Rails 4 application using SQLite3 in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **dead simplest** way to do this, no JavaScript etc., would be to make a link

```
= link_to 'Save', albums_url({ :album => { :artist_name => album['artistName'], :collection_name => album['collectionName'], :primary_genre_name => album['primaryGenreName'] }) , method: 'post'
```

where the hash argument to `albums_url(hash_argument)` is the parameters for the album.

Comment: Just what I needed, appreciate it.